# Quero mudara a cor de varios elementos ao mesmo tempo com JavaScript

Tags: javascript, css, html5

```js
 <script>
      function mCor(){
        document.getElementById("body").style.backgroundColor="black";
        document.getElementById("text").style.color="white";
        document.getElementById("night").style.backgroundColor="white";
        document.getElementById("night").style.color="black";
        
      }
    </script>
```

```html
 <div class="container pt-3">
      <div class="row"><div class="col-10"></div><div class="col-2"><button id="night" onclick="mCor();">night mode</button></div></div>
      <div class="row"><div class="col-12">
         <h2 id="text">Quanto determinado aparelho acescenta na sua conta de luz?</h2><br>
        <p id="text">Para descobrir quanto um aparelho acrescenta na conta de luz, basta informar os dados dele abaixo e clicar em 'CALCULAR'. Lembre-se watts não é igual a KiloWatts hora. Use ponto '.' ao invés de virgula nos números decimas.</p>
      </div></div>
       
    </div>
    <hr>
    <div class="container pt-3"><p id="text">Informe quantas horas por dia seu equipamento fica ligado:</p>
    <input type="text" placeholder="HORAS" id="hora"><br><br>
    <p id="text">Informe quantos dias por mes seu equipamento fica ligado:</p>
    <input type="text" placeholder="DIAS" id="dias"><br><br>
    <p id="text">Informe o consumo em watts(W) do aparelho (W ≠ kW/h):</p>
    <input type="text" placeholder="WATTS" id="w"><br><br>
    <p id="text">Informe o valor da tarifa de sua operadora:</p>
    <input type="text" placeholder="TARIFA" id="tarifa"><br><br>

    <p id="resultado">RESULTADO: </p>
    <button onclick="caucularLuz();" class="btn btn-outline-primary" id="calc">CALCULAR</button>
    </div>
```

Boa tarde. Estou estudando JavaScript tentando fazer um "modo noturno" no site. Adicionei id="text" em todos os p e H1 do html e no Script eu fiz uma função que mudou a cor do fundo para escuro ao clicar no botão, e quero mudar todos os textos para branco, porém apenas o primeiro  mudou de cor. Como posso mudar todos eles de cor de uma só vez?

código que usei para mudar a cor do texto: ' document.getElementById("text").style.color="white"; '

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Posta todos o seu html, para conseguirmos te ajudar melhor. Do jeito que você está explicando, o seu problema acontece porque possivelmente você está colocando o seu Id `text` apenas no primeiro texto na marcação do seu Html

Comment: Isto responde à sua pergunta? [Como alterar o estilo de uma página ao clicar em um botão?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/526594/como-alterar-o-estilo-de-uma-p%c3%a1gina-ao-clicar-em-um-bot%c3%a3o)

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Você pode usar o recurso do próprio HTML
< font color="white">< /font>, e colocar todo texto do seu site dentro da TAG.